# Specify PHP version with dotcloud

Tags: dotcloud

I have an application that requires PHP 5.3.  Is it possible to specify what version of PHP to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to specify the version of PHP in the [PHP and PHP-Worker services](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/php/).  The current version (as of this posting) is 5.4.6-2~lucid+1

If you need a specific version of PHP, it may be possible to use a custom recipe to download and install the specific version your looking for.  The following project is an example of such a custom service.

https://github.com/kencochrane/php-on-dotcloud

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.  Seems do-able, but takes away a lot of the simplicity of PaaS.  Once it is setup you still get the advantage PaaS deployment and scaling.

Comment: FYI, I the documentation on this is hard to find.  I located the old version and the guessed the URL of this: http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/services/custom/